# Parsing YANG Model in java

Tags: java, ietf-netmod-yang

How do I parse YANG models in java ? 
I need to convert the yang model into a xml format.

I have already tried pyang. But since it is in python, it does not suite my requirement.

Comment: I finally used the Yangtools from OpenDaylight project.
See https://wiki.opendaylight.org/view/Main_Page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, that's true.

Use yang-parser-impl from Open daylight.
It provides a yang parser  and returns a set of parsed modules.
Which you can further query to get more node objects.

Comment: yes, indeed.. following is the code..

 `YangParserImpl parser = new YangParserImpl();
 Set<Module> modules = parser.parseYangModels(new File(file), new File(file).getParentFile());
  `

Answer (score 1):

The above API is valid for previous versions. Use the following API for the current version

```
    YangTextSchemaContextResolver yangContextResolver = YangTextSchemaContextResolver.create("yang-context-resolver");

    yangContextResolver.registerSource(new URL("file:///home/ABA/XXX/Workspaces/ABC/X/config.yang"));
    yangContextResolver.registerSource(new URL("file:///home/ABC/XXX/Workspaces/ABC/X/XXX-YY.yang"));


    Optional<SchemaContext> sc = yangContextResolver.getSchemaContext();
```

Comment: And this is for beryllium

Answer (score 0):

you can use [Yangkit](https://github.com/yang-central/yangkit) parser.

maven dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.github.yang-central.yangkit</groupId>
    <artifactId>yangkit-parser</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.2</version>
</dependency>

YangSchemaContext schemaContext = YangYinParser.parse("yangdir");
schemaContext.validate();
```