# Yang parsing in JAVA

Tags: java, parsing, ietf-netmod-yang

I was looking to find a YANG parser and came across this question

[Parsing YANG Model in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24950398/parsing-yang-model-in-java?newreg=fbf3148c7dba490382b2c7e9f96f37bf)

I was wondering if there's any documentation for yang tools - API documentation or examples?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

Try to check yangtools project in Opendaylight github. There is a folder named docs. If you try to compile it with maven, some documents will be created. 
I hope that they can help you.

Regards